# Same Attribute Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'sequence' whenever I am using classes

Tags: python, function, class

I have encountered similar problems in both practice tasks and assignments. I hope that someone here could explain why I always encounter the same error for classes. I have tried self.sequence or sequence in another function but I have the same Attribute Error.

I wanted to design a class to hold a protein sequence and return a sequence length.

```
class ProtSeq():
'''A class that holds a protein sequence'''

    def __init__(self, sequence, identifier, length, function=''):
        '''Initialise the class'''
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.function = function # optional functional description
        self.length = length
    
    def seq(self):
        sequence = AAcodes
        return sequence
    
    def seq_length(self):
        length = len(self.sequence) # this is the part that has Attribute Error
        return print('Length of {} is {} amino acids. '.format(self.sequence,length))

AAcodes = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'
ProtSeq.seq_length(AAcodes)
```

Comment: You are not using the class as you should. You need to instantiate the class (i.e. create instance of that class), then call the `seq_length()` method, without any arguments. Also, `seq()` methods would raise error if there is no global variable `AAcodes`. Overall this method looks redundant

Comment: Then, `return print(...` will return `None`, because `print()` returns `None`

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense to pass `length` to `__init__()`. It's unclear what `identifier` and `function` arguments are intended for

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your formatting is a little messed up so I'm rewriting it here

```
class ProtSeq(): 
    '''A class that holds a protein sequence'''
    def __init__(self, sequence, identifier, length, function=''):
        '''Initialise the class'''
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.function = function # optional functional description
        self.length = length

    def seq(self):
        sequence = AAcodes
        return sequence

    def seq_length(self):
        length = len(self.sequence) # this is the part that has Attribute Error
        return print('Length of {} is {} amino acids. '.format(self.sequence,length))
    
AAcodes = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY' 
ProtSeq.seq_length(AAcodes)
```

The class definition itself is fine, but the way you're trying to use the class is the issue. When you say `AAcodes = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY'`, you're making a string called `AAcodes`. Then you're trying to use seq_length as a static method and passing `AAcodes` as the `self` variable.

This is not how the class is meant to be used.

What you should be doing is creating a ProtSeq object, passing AAcodes as the sequence, and then calling `seq_length` on that object.

```
AAcodes = 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY' 
my_sequence = ProtSeq(AAcodes, 'some identifier', 'some length')
my_sequence.seq_length()
```

Other enhancements:
Because `length` isn't some arbitrary thing that can be set, it should really not be a parameter of `__init__`, but instead be calculated.

```
def __init__(self, sequence, identifier, function=''):
    '''Initialise the class'''
    self.identifier = identifier
    self.sequence = sequence
    self.function = function # optional functional description
    self.length = len(sequence)
```

Comment: `length` should be property, dynamically returned every time when attribute is accesed

Comment: Hi Simon thank you for your help, I know how to edit this now.